# change a mouseenter event into a timed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I have the following code that works excellent for a **mouseenter** event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".someClass").mouseenter(function () {

        //does some stuff

        }).mouseleave(function () {
        //does some stuff

        });
});
```

What I am looking for is to change the above so that it is a **timed event** and does not require the mouse to enter the DIV with the associated class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

jmcall10

Comment: What do you mean by "timed event"? Should it occur after a specific time, no matter what happens? In which case look into `setTimeout`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Basically I want the event to start (say after 2 seconds) and then then the "mouseleave" event to trigger (say after 4 seconds). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (If that's the case, I'll add some comments)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.someClass')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      console.log('mouse entered');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      console.log('mouse exited');
    });
  
  setTimeout(function() { $('.someClass').trigger('mouseenter'); }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() { $('.someClass').trigger('mouseleave'); }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="someClass">Enter your mouse here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a timed event: `setTimeout(fun, 1000);`

Then trigger event which you want in `fun`: `$('.someClass').dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseenter');`

May can help you...